# Filter_all() with a negate str_detect approach

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Hello dear colleagues,

First thing first, this is my first time I'm asking a question here so I hope I'll be clear.
I'm currently facing some challenges when dealing with a lot of dataframes with variable lengths and non-regular colnames. The challenge is to remove unwanted rows (here rows for samples sequenced as Whole genome shotgun sequencing) matching multiple keywords, indeed it would we to easy to have a single keyword ... For that purpose I'm unsing `filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "WGS"))`. However, trying to negate the code with `negate=T` or `!str_detect()` return the whole dataframe and nothing seems to work. Using `all_vars()` remove every rows in the df.
I came around a solution but I find it quite heavy and I'm pretty sure there is a better way to perform this :

```
> tmp <- metadata[["PRJNA237362"]]  
> no <- tmp %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "WGS")))  
> final <- tmp[tmp$Run %notin% no$Run,]
```

I'm not very familiar with the tidyverse, still a lot to learn, so I might have missed something here.
I don't understand why `filter` returns the whole df when negating the expression

Thanks to whoever answers !
Have a great day.
Rémy

---

A reproducible example of what I'm dealing with

```
> data(msleep)  
> msleep%>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "omni"))) %>% glimpse()  
> msleep%>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "omni", negate=T))) %>% glimpse()   
> no <- msleep %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "omni"))) %>% glimpse()  
> yes <- msleep[msleep$vore %notin% no$vore,] %>% glimpse()
```

Here a part of df I'm actually working on :

```
> df = structure(list(Run = c("ERR2804817", "ERR2804818", "ERR2804819", 
"ERR2804820", "ERR2804821", "ERR2834367", "ERR2834371", "ERR2834373", 
"ERR2834374", "ERR2834375", "ERR2834376", "ERR2834377", "ERR2834379", 
"ERR2828323", "ERR2828326", "ERR2828327", "ERR2828328", "ERR2828330"
), LibraryLayout = c("PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", 
"PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", "PAIRED", 
"PAIRED", "PAIRED", "SINGLE", "SINGLE", "SINGLE", "SINGLE", "SINGLE"
), Library.Name = c("Bangladeshi_2yr", "Bangladeshi_2yr", "Bangladeshi_2yr", 
"Bangladeshi_2yr", "Bangladeshi_2yr", "table S7A,B; WGS", "table S7A,B; WGS", 
"table S7A,B; WGS", "table S7A,B; WGS", "table S7A,B; WGS", "table S7A,B; WGS", 
"table S7A,B; WGS", "table S7A,B; WGS", "table S12", "table S12", 
"table S12", "table S12", "table S12"), LibrarySource = c("METAGENOMIC", 
"METAGENOMIC", "METAGENOMIC", "METAGENOMIC", "METAGENOMIC", "GENOMIC", 
"GENOMIC", "GENOMIC", "GENOMIC", "GENOMIC", "GENOMIC", "GENOMIC", 
"GENOMIC", "METATRANSCRIPTOMIC", "METATRANSCRIPTOMIC", "METATRANSCRIPTOMIC", 
"METATRANSCRIPTOMIC", "METATRANSCRIPTOMIC"), Instrument = c("Illumina MiSeq", 
"Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", 
"Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", 
"Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", "Illumina MiSeq", 
"NextSeq 500", "NextSeq 500", "NextSeq 500", "NextSeq 500", "NextSeq 500"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 806L, 807L, 808L, 809L, 810L), class = "data.frame")

> #Here is what I have for now
> `%notin%` = Negate(`%in%`)
> tmp = metadata %>% filter_all(any_vars(everything(), str_detect(., "shotgun|WGS|whole genome|all_genome|WXS|WholeGenomeShotgun|Whole genome shotgun|Metatranscriptomic|WXS")))
> meta= meta[meta$Run%notin%tmp$Run,]
```

Ultimately, I would like to make something like that :

```
> tmp = meta %>% filter_all(any_vars(!str_detect(., "shotgun|WGS|whole genome|all_genome|WXS|WholeGenomeShotgun|Whole genome shotgun|Metatranscriptomic|WXS")))
> #OR this version
> tmp = meta %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "shotgun|WGS|whole genome|all_genome|WXS|WholeGenomeShotgun|Whole genome shotgun|Metatranscriptomic|WXS", negate=T)))
```

The trick is that I can't predict the colnames of my df nor the dimension of my df so I wrote `for()` loops with a conditions to detect pattern, remove them and write a new file with the cleaned df.

For now my code is working but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Thanks a lot.

---

```
> packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.3.0’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.5’
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rmdformats_1.0.1 ggpubr_0.4.0     forcats_0.5.1    stringr_1.4.0   
 [5] dplyr_1.0.5      purrr_0.3.4      readr_1.4.0      tidyr_1.1.3     
 [9] tibble_3.1.0     tidyverse_1.3.0  ade4_1.7-16      factoextra_1.0.7
[13] ggplot2_3.3.3    FactoMineR_2.4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2           jsonlite_1.7.2       prettydoc_0.4.1     
 [4] carData_3.0-4        modelr_0.1.8         assertthat_0.2.1    
 [7] cellranger_1.1.0     yaml_2.2.1           progress_1.2.2      
[10] ggrepel_0.9.1        pillar_1.5.1         backports_1.2.1     
[13] lattice_0.20-41      glue_1.4.2           digest_0.6.27       
[16] ggsignif_0.6.1       rvest_0.3.6          colorspace_2.0-0    
[19] cowplot_1.1.1        htmltools_0.5.1.1    pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[22] broom_0.7.5          haven_2.3.1          bookdown_0.21       
[25] scales_1.1.1         openxlsx_4.2.3       rio_0.5.26          
[28] farver_2.1.0         generics_0.1.0       car_3.0-10          
[31] ellipsis_0.3.1       DT_0.17              withr_2.4.1         
[34] cli_2.3.1            magrittr_2.0.1       crayon_1.4.1        
[37] readxl_1.3.1         evaluate_0.14        fs_1.5.0            
[40] fansi_0.4.2          MASS_7.3-53.1        rstatix_0.7.0       
[43] xml2_1.3.2           foreign_0.8-81       tools_4.0.4         
[46] data.table_1.14.0    prettyunits_1.1.1    hms_1.0.0           
[49] lifecycle_1.0.0      munsell_0.5.0        reprex_1.0.0        
[52] zip_2.1.1            cluster_2.1.1        flashClust_1.01-2   
[55] compiler_4.0.4       rlang_0.4.10         grid_4.0.4          
[58] rstudioapi_0.13      htmlwidgets_1.5.3    leaps_3.1           
[61] labeling_0.4.2       rmarkdown_2.7        gtable_0.3.0        
[64] abind_1.4-5          DBI_1.1.1            curl_4.3            
[67] R6_2.5.0             lubridate_1.7.10     knitr_1.31          
[70] utf8_1.2.1           stringi_1.5.3        Rcpp_1.0.6          
[73] vctrs_0.3.6          scatterplot3d_0.3-41 dbplyr_2.1.0        
[76] tidyselect_1.1.0     xfun_0.22
```

Comment: Hi viellette, you can share part of your data frame with `dput(head(yourDataFrame, 10))`, where 10 is the amount of rows you think it should be enough to reproduce the issue and get to a solution. Then copy the result and add to your question.

Comment: also provide `packageVersion("dplyr")` some relevant functions are available only after dplyr 1.0.3 or 1.0.4.

Comment: Done. 
Sorry forgot the R session info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second edit based on updated information:**

Another way to approach this is to do a rowwise operation and add a matching column based on your chosen regex matches:

If you want to keep the NA values in your final filter then this should work:

```
regex_match <- "omni"
msleep %>% 
rowwise() %>%
mutate(regex_match = any(str_detect(c_across(is.character), 
regex(regex_match)), na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(!regex_match)
```

If you want to exclude the NAs, then add a replace_na() step:

```
msleep %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(regex_match = any(str_detect(c_across(is.character), regex("omni")), na.rm = FALSE),
         regex_match = replace_na(regex_match, TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(!regex_match)
```

So the first version with your metadata:

```
regex_match <-  "shotgun|WGS|whole genome|all_genome|WXS|WholeGenomeShotgun|Whole genome shotgun|Metatranscriptomic|WXS"
metadata %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(regex_match = any(str_detect(c_across(is.character), regex(regex_match)), na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!regex_match)
```

**Edit 1**

I think the problem lies in the combination of a negation with the syntax `any_vars`, which means you are returning the whole dataframe because every column has a row with values not containing "omni" or "WGS" from your data.

With the latest version of dplyr syntax, you could try the following:

```
msleep %>% filter(if_all(starts_with("vore"), ~!str_detect(.x, "omni")))
```

This focuses on just the one column, or

```
msleep %>% filter(if_all(everything(), ~!str_detect(.x, "omni")))
```

for the entire dataframe.

Does that get what you need?

Comment: I apologize, this version is working also (the second proposition for my precise problem). I was confused byt the dimension fo the msleep df but I figured that NA are also drop on this df.

Comment: I think the first version of my updated edit should work now and keep the NA values.

Comment: And it can be achieved in an even simpler way, though you are losing control over how to deal with NAs: `metadata %>%  unite(new, remove = FALSE) %>% mutate(not_found = str_detect(.$new, regex(regex_match), negate = TRUE)) %>% filter(not_found) %>%  select(-c(new,not_found))`

Comment: Thank you for this update/response. 
Both the propositions seems to work fine !
Out of curiosity I ran both your propositions and my code. The ```rowwise() %>% mutate()``` version is actually much slower than the ```unite()%>% mutate()``` and my code, your second proposition result in the exact same time of completion. 
Thank you for your time, it helped a lot.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@Marcelo Avila and @awaji98 propositions works on my problem. However, I would like to show that this code as a subtility in the fact that it seems NA are removed with the propositions above:

````
msleep%>% filter_all(all_vars(str_detect(., "omni", negate=T)))```

msleep %>% filter(if_all(everything(), ~!str_detect(.x, "omni")))

msleep %>% 
  filter(if_all(
    .cols = everything(),
    .fns = ~ stringr::str_detect(.x, "omni", negate = TRUE))
  )
````

```
no <- msleep %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "omni")))

no
# A tibble: 20 x 11
   name     genus  vore  order  conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Owl mon… Aotus  omni  Prima… NA                  17         1.8      NA    
 2 Greater… Blari… omni  Soric… lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133
 3 Grivet   Cerco… omni  Prima… lc                  10         0.7      NA    
 4 Star-no… Condy… omni  Soric… lc                  10.3       2.2      NA    
 5 African… Crice… omni  Roden… NA                   8.3       2        NA    
 6 Lesser … Crypt… omni  Soric… lc                   9.1       1.4       0.15 
 7 North A… Didel… omni  Didel… lc                  18         4.9       0.333
 8 Europea… Erina… omni  Erina… lc                  10.1       3.5       0.283
 9 Patas m… Eryth… omni  Prima… lc                  10.9       1.1      NA    
10 Galago   Galago omni  Prima… NA                   9.8       1.1       0.55 
11 Human    Homo   omni  Prima… NA                   8         1.9       1.5  
12 Macaque  Macaca omni  Prima… NA                  10.1       1.2       0.75 
13 Chimpan… Pan    omni  Prima… NA                   9.7       1.4       1.42 
14 Baboon   Papio  omni  Prima… NA                   9.4       1         0.667
15 Potto    Perod… omni  Prima… lc                  11        NA        NA    
16 African… Rhabd… omni  Roden… NA                   8.7      NA        NA    
17 Squirre… Saimi… omni  Prima… NA                   9.6       1.4      NA    
18 Pig      Sus    omni  Artio… domesticated         9.1       2.4       0.5  
19 Tenrec   Tenrec omni  Afros… NA                  15.6       2.3      NA    
20 Tree sh… Tupaia omni  Scand… NA                   8.9       2.6       0.233
# … with 3 more variables: awake <dbl>, brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
```

We find 20 rows that contains the pattern "omni"

```
no <- msleep %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "omni")))
msleep[msleep$vore %notin% no$vore,]

# A tibble: 63 x 11
   name     genus  vore  order  conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Cheetah  Acino… carni Carni… lc                  12.1      NA        NA    
 2 Mountai… Aplod… herbi Roden… nt                  14.4       2.4      NA    
 3 Cow      Bos    herbi Artio… domesticated         4         0.7       0.667
 4 Three-t… Brady… herbi Pilosa NA                  14.4       2.2       0.767
 5 Norther… Callo… carni Carni… vu                   8.7       1.4       0.383
 6 Vesper … Calom… NA    Roden… NA                   7        NA        NA    
 7 Dog      Canis  carni Carni… domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333
 8 Roe deer Capre… herbi Artio… lc                   3        NA        NA    
 9 Goat     Capri  herbi Artio… lc                   5.3       0.6      NA    
10 Guinea … Cavis  herbi Roden… domesticated         9.4       0.8       0.217
# … with 53 more rows, and 3 more variables: awake <dbl>, brainwt <dbl>,
#   bodywt <dbl>
```

This remove efficiently the 20 rows and return 63 rows df.
However, because of the NA it seems that the following code (and the others above) return a wrong df.

```
library(tidyverse)
msleep %>% 
  filter(
    if_all(
      everything(), 
      ~stringr::str_detect(., "omni", negate = T)
    )
  )
 A tibble: 15 x 11
   name     genus  vore  order  conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Cow      Bos    herbi Artio… domesticated         4         0.7       0.667
 2 Dog      Canis  carni Carni… domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333
 3 Guinea … Cavis  herbi Roden… domesticated         9.4       0.8       0.217
 4 Chinchi… Chinc… herbi Roden… domesticated        12.5       1.5       0.117
 5 Long-no… Dasyp… carni Cingu… lc                  17.4       3.1       0.383
 6 Big bro… Eptes… inse… Chiro… lc                  19.7       3.9       0.117
 7 Horse    Equus  herbi Peris… domesticated         2.9       0.6       1    
 8 Domesti… Felis  carni Carni… domesticated        12.5       3.2       0.417
 9 Golden … Mesoc… herbi Roden… en                  14.3       3.1       0.2  
10 House m… Mus    herbi Roden… nt                  12.5       1.4       0.183
11 Rabbit   Oryct… herbi Lagom… domesticated         8.4       0.9       0.417
12 Laborat… Rattus herbi Roden… lc                  13         2.4       0.183
13 Eastern… Scalo… inse… Soric… lc                   8.4       2.1       0.167
14 Thirtee… Sperm… herbi Roden… lc                  13.8       3.4       0.217
15 Brazili… Tapir… herbi Peris… vu                   4.4       1         0.9  
# … with 3 more variables: awake <dbl>, brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
```

There is something weird when negating the `str_detect()`.
If anyone has an insight on this it would be tremendous as I fear I will have trouble sleeping tonight.

Thanks a lot,
Cheers from Paris.

Comment: ah, now I see you you meant :)

Comment: internally `NA`s are logicals  (see `typeof(NA)`). Maybe this is the underlaying reason why it works not exactly like expected. There are 3 logicals, `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA`. str_detect() seems to treat `NA` equally, regardless of argument `negate`.

Comment: Take a look at @awaji98 updated response, the ```unite()``` approach is elegant and works pretty well !
Anyway thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned multiple keywords, you can pass multiple keywords to `str_detect()` with the regex `|` (or) operator.

The following lines will filter out (via `negate = TRUE` all rows where at least one variable has at least one of the given patterns `ui|Br|Ch|lis`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

keywords_to_remove <- c("ui", "Br", "lis", "Ch", "omni")
keywords_regex <- paste0(keywords_to_remove, collapse = "|")
  
msleep %>% 
  filter(if_all(
    .cols = everything(),
    .fns = ~ stringr::str_detect(.x, keywords_regex, negate = TRUE))
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 x 11
#>   name   genus  vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Cow    Bos    herbi Arti… domesticated         4         0.7       0.667  20  
#> 2 Dog    Canis  carni Carn… domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333  13.9
#> 3 Long-… Dasyp… carni Cing… lc                  17.4       3.1       0.383   6.6
#> 4 Horse  Equus  herbi Peri… domesticated         2.9       0.6       1      21.1
#> 5 Golde… Mesoc… herbi Rode… en                  14.3       3.1       0.2     9.7
#> 6 House… Mus    herbi Rode… nt                  12.5       1.4       0.183  11.5
#> 7 Rabbit Oryct… herbi Lago… domesticated         8.4       0.9       0.417  15.6
#> 8 Labor… Rattus herbi Rode… lc                  13         2.4       0.183  11  
#> 9 Easte… Scalo… inse… Sori… lc                   8.4       2.1       0.167  15.6
#> # … with 2 more variables: brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] '1.0.5'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Marcel and @awaji98 for your response. 
I tried your propositions and I'm still on the same problem.
Correct me if i'm wrong but filter(
    if_any( everything(), ~ stringr::str_detect(.,))) 
and filter(if_all(everything(), ~!str_detect(.x, "omni"))) 
are equal to filter_all(any_vars(...)) or filter_all(all_vars(...)).
Both Your propositions gave the same results as my post. 
I would like to share a df to explain it better but I don't find any way to share it.

Comment: @awaji98 The problem I have here is that the column (in my real code) vary in every df and I want to remove rows containing the pattern related to "WGS", if I use all_vars or if_all it will remove every rows on my df. 
What I don't understand is why when I negate my ```str_detect()``` by either ! or ```negate=T``` it won't return the negate df.

Comment: Marcelo, what I'm trying to do is remove the "omni" from the df, keep everything but "omni". If you try : 
```library(tidyverse)
msleep %>% 
  filter( if_any(everything(), ~! stringr::str_detect(., "omni") ) )```
This will return the whole df instead of removing the expected values : "omni".
This is what I'm looking for : 
```no <- msleep %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "omni")))  

final<- msleep[msleep$vore %notin% no$vore,]```

Comment: edited the answer, maybe it helps, otherwise provide a sample of your data and I hope to better understand what you aim :)

Comment: to be honest, I never get those in  the first go as well, always get confused with if_all and if_any. In any case, the `filter_all(any_vars())` is deprecated (see `?filter_all`). So I would suggest using the second version. I also cannot clearly see why the filter_all() version doesns't work. But don't worry. I am sure it is pretty common to have to try multiple times until you get it right.

Comment: UPDATE
This version clearly does something but dimension of the df seems to be wrong on the msleep. Indeed, using the same code but with only **omni** or ```"omni|Galago" gives not the expected df dimensions. Allways come back to 15x11 tibble. I guess this code removes NA. 
On my df it seems to work fine but I need to verify it in my loops.

Comment: i am quite sure it works fine. maybe every instance of omni is also a instace of galago or vice-versa.

Comment: maybe better to write a new question.